# Is there any simple way of Comparing two graphs in neo4j

Tags: java, eclipse, neo4j

My back-end generates a graph that contains a node (lets call it Node 1), the graph looks as follows

```
                    1                (TOPNODE)
                                    /       \
                    2               1        2
                                  /  \
                    3             3   4
                                /     \
                    4           5      6
```

The top node contains the date the graph was generated.

After that all the even levels (level 2 and level 4 which contain nodes 1, 2,5 and 6) contain a unique name, and a value ie. a phone number.

All of the odd levels (level 3 AKA: nodes 3 and 4) contain their parent name and their children information.

In my service I can edit parts of the graph. For example: I can change the value in the node (NOT THE NAME). or I can delete nodes at once. But i cna only access the edited information by generating that part of the subgraph.

SO my question is: Can I get the full graph into JAVA, then compare only that subgraph with the new subgraph that was just generated and then create a new version of the old graph but with the changes?

What I have tried is:
pulling all of the graph into java as a JSON, and using that to compare to the smaller graph, this works. But I dont know if there is a more efficient way or if there is any way to get the nodes in java as actual nodes instead of JSON. To get it into a JSON I did the following:

```
     Session session = driver.session();
    String message = "START n=node(*) MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m;";
    StatementResult result = session.run(message);
    while ( result.hasNext() ) {
        Record record = result.next();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(record.asMap()));
        String m = gson.toJson(record.asMap().get("n"));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(record.asMap()));
        convert(json,m);
    }
    session.close();
```

Comment: Yes, there is. Show us what you've tried. How have you thought about the problem?

Comment: Hi i just added what I have done